# Tkinter Text widget unusable after displaying a tkinter.simpledialog prompt

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

In Tkinter I find a small problem. I am unable to use an Entry/Text/Scrolledtext/any widget that the user can enter letters into after using a Tkinter simpledialog prompt. The entry widget works fine before using the prompt, but after the prompt I am unable to enter stuff into the widget. It's as though the widget becomes disabled. No exception is thrown. However, I can access the widget again once I click on another window and click on my Tkinter window again.

I have tried using the `focus_get` method on the entry widget. It doesn't work.
I have also tried doing `entry.config(state='normal')`. That doesn't work.
I could not think of anything else to try. Searching the web doesn't work; nothing relevant comes up.

Here's some example code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog as dialog

def get_string():
    string = dialog.askstring("Title", "Prompt")
    print(string)

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
button = tk.Button(root, text="Get String", command=get_string)

entry.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

For the problem to show, you need to click on the button, and then try to use the entry widget; it doesn't work for me.

I am using Python 3.9.6, on macOS.

Edit: after a few people commented, this problem is probably specific to macOS Big Sur; this problem isn't there on Windows, OSX, or Linux.

Comment: It works for me. (Windows 11)

Comment: @Sujay When I was using Windows as well, it did work, but after I transitioned to macOS it doesn't work.

Comment: @Matiiss No, I mean after the prompt is closed, then the entry widget is inaccessible.

Comment: @DaniyalWarraich ok, can't reproduce that problem tho, any other particular behavior you want to mention? or does that always happen no matter how you try? any other issues? what happens if you have multiple entry boxes? (silly question, but can you reproduce the issue with the given code?

Comment: @Matiiss is always happens with the Entry/Text widgets. On Windows I never had this problem; it's only on macOS I have it.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem in Linux either, it seems specific to macOS

Comment: Your code works fine for me on OSX

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm running Big Sur.

Comment: @j_4321 it probably is specific to macOS Big Sur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I left the project alone for a while, and now I've updated to macOS Monterey and Python 3.10. With these updates, I now find the problem disappeared.